# JavaScript event click triggered twice

Tags: javascript, events, click

I am testing creating LI elements with one simple hyperlink inside each element.
All the LI elements are generated on the fly using jQuery.append

However -- 
1. if the elements are created as part of CALLBACK function (ASYNCHRONOUS) -- after calling jQuery AJAX -- all works normally
2. if the elements are created SYNCHRONOUSLY -- it will triggered two click events once clicked.

Here below are three related JavaScript function? And notice there are two hardcoded hyperlinks 1. labeled as  SYNC 2. labeled as A-SYNC.

Any idea?

```
    MCRM.Handler.accounts_index = function(){
    console.log("MCRM.Handler.accounts_index");
        MCRM.Account.all(function(r){
            MCRM.Handler.accounts_list(r);
            preventDefaultLink();
        });
    };



    MCRM.Handler.accounts_list = function(r){
          console.log("MCRM.Handler.accounts_list");
          $('#listAccount').append('<li class="arrow"><a href="app/views/accounts/show.html">A-SYNC</a></li>');
          for(var  i = 0; i < r.length; i ++) {
            record = r[i];
            $('#listAccount').append('<li class="arrow">' + MCRM.AccountsHelper.account_link(record) + '</li>');
          }
    };

    MCRM.Account.all = function(success_callback2, options){
            var accounts;
            console.log("MCRM.Account.all");
            $('#listAccount').append('<li class="arrow"><a href="app/views/accounts/show.html">SYNC</a></li>');
            var soap = "",
            url = MCRM.SIEBEL_URL + "/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&UserName=" + MCRM.SIEBEL_USER + "&Password=" + MCRM.SIEBEL_PWD
            soap = MCRM.XML_MY_ACCOUNTS;   
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "post", url: url, contentType: "text/xml", data: soap, dataType: "xml", processData: false,
                success: function( doc, status){
                  console.log("SUCCESS");
                  var json = jQuery.xml2json(doc);
                  //var account = json.Body.SiebelAccountQueryByIdResponse.SiebelMessage.ListOfAccountInterface.Account;
                  MCRM.Account.accounts = json.Body.Siebel_spcAccount_SiebelAccountQueryByExample_Output.ListOfAccountInterface.Account;
                  success_callback2(MCRM.Account.accounts);
                  //MCRM.screen.account_detail.setValue(account.Name + "<br>" + account.MainPhoneNumber);
                },
              });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

i found my issue is due to 
preventDefaultLink();

that contain event listener for 'click' event was called twice. I just knew that attaching it twice will impact in double event.